# Get the layer shape when construct Graph in TensoFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

when I used

```
    concat = tf.concat([query_rep, title_rep, cos_similarity], axis=1)
    print(concat.shape[1].value)
    # query_rep + title_rep + cos_similarity
    hidden_size = concat.shape[1]
```

I found I can't get the concat shape, it will return `None`. I has to specifically assign a value to `hidden_size`, e.g. `hidden_size=201`. How can I do to get the shape automatically?

In addition, for my `CNN` networks, I want to padding the input sequence in each batch rather than in whole dataset. so I have to make the `max_len` a `placeholder`, but then I find that a `placeholder` can not serve as another `placeholder`'s parameters. e.g. following codes do not work

```
    self.max_len = tf.placeholder(int32)
    self.query_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self.max_len])
```

how can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two "kinds" of shapes: the *static* shape that can be inferred at compile time and the *dynamic* shape which is only known during runtime. To get the static shape you can call `my_tensor.get_shape()` on a tensor, to access the dynamic shape you can call `tf.shape(my_tensor)`. If `get_shape()` returns `None` then the shape can only be known dynamically. If you have additional information about the shape you can set the shape using `my_tensor.set_shape()`.

For your second question, why don't you use

```
self.query_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None])
```

This way both dimensions are variable.

Comment: The second solution looks good! Thanks, but for the first one, `tf.shape(my_tensor)` still cannot get the shape and return wrong information `ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("random_normal:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)` and can not use this shape to create a new layer's parameters `h_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[hidden_size, hidden_size], stddev=0.1), name='h_W')`

Comment: Yes, this is normal. When you create a variable, the shape must be known at compile time, so you cannot use the dynamic shape of another tensor as the shape for a new variable, if that dynamic shape has unknown values (like yours does). You must know `hidden_size` beforehand, which you usually do, because this is a design choice of your architecture.